# this.responseXML is not working while making request to isbndb server

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am working on an App and I am trying to do xmlhttp request in nodejs and express but my responseXML is not working and it returns nothing.. Here is my code:-

```
var XMLHttpRequest=require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xml2js=require("xml2js");


var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){

    console.log("State:"+this.readyState);

    if(this.readyState==4){


        var result=this.responseXML;
        console.log(result);


    }

};

xhr.open("GET","http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=QMMEUNJB&results=prices&index1=isbn&value1=0061031321");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml');

xhr.send();
```

And the output is:-

```
Output:-
State:1
State:1
State:2
State:3
State:4
```

It returns a blank line after State:4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlhttprequest` package doesn't (currently) support XML - see the bottom of https://npmjs.org/package/xmlhttprequest

You're already including the `xml2js` library, but your code doesn't appear to be using it anywhere. Try replacing

```
var result=this.responseXML;
console.log(result);
```

with this:

```
xml2js.parseString(this.responseText, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks .. I didn't know it lacks XML support ... :)

Comment: Yea.. I think XMLhttprequest is kind of a bad name for a library that doesn't do XML...

Comment: Want to mark my answer as correct so that this question doesn't appear to not have a good answer in search results?